# Can I start or Shall i start?

Tags: grammar, american-english

Is CAN I START correct ? 
Is it okay to use it instead of Shall I Start ?
For eg I want to start my presentation in front of class 
So can I say CAN I START  Like I'm asking for permission to start my presentation.
Asking Teacher for permission

Comment: Hi Heya. English Language Lerners is a great site and you can find interesting questions and answers [there](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/146791/difference-between-shall-and-can).

Answer (score -1):

You can use either. “shall” implies that you are seeking consent and permission whereas “can I” implies ability to start (ie. have we fixed the technical problems and are we able to start now?)

I’d say both are correct in this context